# strtok return int type in c

Tags: c, strtok

When I run this code it gave a segmentation fault.

```
main ()
{
    char *line ="2,3,22";
    int size=3,i,j; 
    double value; 
    char *val;

    for (i = 0; i<size ; i++) {
        if (line == NULL) break;
        printf("%s\n",strtok (line ,","));
    }
}
```

and gave a

> ```
> "warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
>  printf("%s\n",strtok (line ,","));"
> ```

So when I assign `strtok` value to char* it gave an error. why `strtok` return an int value? What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's using an implicit prototype for `strtok`. You need to `#include <string.h>` (You might also need to include `stddef.h` for `NULL` and should also include `stdio.h` for `printf`).